# Set a numerical range restriction on the output of a model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train two models together. Both are regression models.
The first model would output a prediction, which is fed into the second model.
The second model is pre-trained to make good predictions (within a certain range of inputs).
The first model is freshly made and it is the model that is being trained here.

My issue is: The pre-trained model only makes good predictions when the data inputted into it is within its training range, in this case between 80 and 700. For numbers larger than 700 or smaller than 80, the pre-trained model might give wrong predictions (it never learned data in those ranges).
However, the first model would make predictions that are larger than 700, which causes the second model to make wrong predictions, which meshes up the training loss. I want the predictions of the first model to only converge at the range of 80 < x < 700. How do I do this? Thank you so much for your help!

---

Also, somethings that I've tried so far:

- Use an if/else statement right after the first model outputs its results. If the output is greater than 700 or less than 80, convert it to zero to get a big loss. However, this if/else seems to only work in eager mode, but it needs to be in my training loop (which runs on graph mode).
- Train the second network to output a big number (error) when receiving inputs greater than 700 or less than 80. This does not work since the model would be less accurate from this.

Comment: I read about graph mode from this [article](https://pub.towardsai.net/improve-the-performance-easily-in-tensorflow-using-graph-mode-288ee35dddae). I am unable to understand why your first method is not working in graph model. Why can't you simply calculate the loss between expected output and your output (outputs less than 80 or greater than 700 turned to zero)?
Also, you can try changing the loss function.

Comment: ^ Yes following the above article the method one worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**There are different techniques that you can try:**

- Remove the outliers when feeding the data to the first model.
- impute the outliers with median value before feeding it to the first model.
- Trim the outliers.
- Use different transformations if the data is skewed and that's the reason for outliers. You can use `log`, `sqrt` or `square` transformations.
- `normalize` or `standardize` your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! To clarify, the original data that is fed into the first model have no outliers. The outliers are generated by the first model's outputs, and they cause a problem because the second model can not correctly predict them.